# Does oracle /netezza execute subqueries only once

Tags: oracle, netezza

In this query:

```
select L1.*, L2.* from (select t1.col1, max(t1.col2) from ($subquery) t1, group by t1.col1) L1, ($subquery) L2 where L1.col1 = L2.col1
```

Will Oracle/Netezza execute the $subquery only once? Or twice?

Comment: Please write your SQL using ANSI `JOIN` instead of joining in your `WHERE` clause. You can also use the `WITH` clause to define your subquery up front instead of writing it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will execute two times. (Actually this isn't 100% accurate. It will execute only the main (compound) query once, but probably it will access the subquery's table's 2 different times/way.)

You should use `with` for optimizing this way.

(Otherwise you could use MAX() OVER (PARTITION BY ....) for similar things as well.)